# Why is `doesFilterPass` not being called in this custom filter

Tags: ag-grid-react

It's my understanding that when `filterChangedCallback` is called that the grid filters the current data and calls `doesFilterPass` and `isFilterActive` as it does so.

Here I have column that uses a custom filter, and a floating filter. The floating filter (a checkbox) gets displayed ok, and when I click on it `onFloatingFilterChanged` in the custom filter is called, the green filter active icon appears, and the grid refreshes, but `doesFilterPass` does not get called at all and I can't figure out why.

There's something fundamental I'm not getting with custom filters so if anyone can shed any light on this I'd be grateful.

(Edit: it may be the interplay between the custom/floating filters that's at issue. There was a similar ag-grid-angular issue [posted to github last year](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/2469) but nothing came of that. So perhaps it's a bug?)

#### Custom filter

```
export default class BooleanFilter {

  init(params) {
    this.params = params;
    this.valueGetter = params.valueGetter;
    this.filterChangedCallback = params.filterChangedCallback;
    this.status = false;
  }

  onFloatingFilterChanged(status) {
    this.status = status;
    this.filterChangedCallback();
  }

  getGui() {
    return '<div />';
  }

  getModel() {
    return this.isFilterActive() ? { filterType: 'boolean', filter: this.status } : undefined;
  }

  setModel(model) {
    this.state.status = model ? model.value : '';
  }

  isFilterActive() {
    return this.status === true;
  }

  doesFilterPass(params) {
    console.log(this.status, params);
  }

}
```

#### Floating filter

```
export default class FloatingCheckboxFilter extends Component {

  state = { status: false };

  handleToggle = (e) => {
    const { target: { checked } } = e;
    const { parentFilterInstance } = this.props;
    this.setState({ status: checked });
    parentFilterInstance((instance) => {
      instance.onFloatingFilterChanged(checked);
    });
  }

  onParentModelChanged = (parentModel) => {
    this.setState({
      status: !parentModel ? false : parentModel.filter
    });
  }

  render() {

    const { status } = this.state;

    return (
      <input
        style={{ marginTop: '0.75em' }}
        type="checkbox"
        checked={status}
        onChange={this.handleToggle}
      />
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: 0

According to the AG grid documentation: The floating set filter is not editable, so no method is exposed on the parent filter for the floating filter to call.

And for this reason, no method of the lifecycle is being called.

Source: https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/component-floating-filter/#floating-filter-methods-on-provided-filters